# The A,B, and C building or The A, B, and C buildings

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct?

> There will be repairs on the A, B, and C building?

or

> There will be repairs on the A, B, and C buildings.

I think it's the latter because the sentence is referring to multiple buildings.

Comment: The latter is correct but remove the comma after B. But that is an assumption because there is no context. "The A, B and C building is on schedule" is also correct. Noun - vs - verb participle.

Comment: @WeatherVane - [Whether there should be a comma after B is a huge stylistic debate.](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/)  My personal feeling is that it should be there.

Comment: @stangdon - I have the opposite feeling, but I have voted your comment +1 because I agree that it is the subject of a stylistic debate.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are grammatically correct; based on the provided context that multiple buildings are being repaired, the second sentence is the correct choice to express that multiple buildings are to be repaired.

The first sentence is saying that a single building, named after three entities, will be repaired. For example: "There will be repairs on the 'Alice, Bob, and Charlie' Lecture Hall."

The second sentence is expressing that multiple buildings are to be repaired. I.e. "There will be repairs on the school, the hospital, and the supermarket".